# How does Micronaut determine tracing instrumentation to be "insufficient"?

Tags: micronaut, open-telemetry, opentracing

From [this](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-tracing/latest/guide/) guide to Micronaut Tracing:

> If the Tracing annotations and existing instrumentations are not sufficient, Micronaut’s tracing integration registers a io.opentracing.Tracer bean which exposes the Open Tracing API and can be dependency-injected as needed.

Considering the OpenTracing project has been deprecated with users being encouraged to migrate to OpenTelemetry, I really want to avoid this behavior.

I have set up tracing with OpenTelemetry through autoconfiguration in Micronaut's `application.yml`, and as far as I can tell everything is working correctly. I've confirmed this using both the logging and OTLP exporters, but I'm unable to disable jaeger as Micronaut still wants to register an `io.opentracing.Tracer`.

I've taken a look at Micronaut's source code but I haven't been able to find the part responsible for making this call. What exactly does Micronaut require before it stops trying to register an OpenTracing tracer? "Not sufficient" is very vague.